# PHP make a string a valid php variable

Tags: php, regex, strip

I read the PHP Variable page and it states the correct way to assign a variable is.
`[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*`

so it is a valid variable thats the official expression.

my question is how can I make a string

```
$string = "not a valid php var, and @ or # or are not allowed";
process_string($string);//should return "notavalidphpvarandororarenotallowed"
```

so all I am asking is to strip off any characters that do not meet the condition on the regex above.

Comment: have you tried anything yourself? If so, show the code, if not do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$str = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff]/", "", $str);

Comment: the start of the string should be handled separately